# RLink fails in Mathematica 12.2.0 Mac OS Catalina

Tags: programming, rlink

Cannot run RLink in mathematica in Catalina. I get a failed error even though the paclet loads. Any pointers?

Comment: Can you, please, provide here the code you have used and the specific error that was returned? This will help us to better help you!

Comment: I reported this a while ago to WRI. In 12.2 RLink doesn't work with the build in version of R. In my opinion this doesn't matter so much because the build in one is quite old. Instead install and use an external version of R. This works even with R 4.0 quite well. There are a couple of posts on this site how to do this. You can also go to Szabolt's page: http://szhorvat.net/pelican/setting-up-rlink-for-mathematica.html

Comment: Thank you so much. Here is the code I ran.

Comment: In[3]:= RLinkResourcesInstall[Update -> True]

Comment: Out[3]= {PacletObject[RLinkRuntime, 9.0.0.0, <>]}

In[4]:= InstallR[]                                                              

InstallR::badpaclet: 
   Could not find a path to R runtime. Possibly the installed RLink runtime is
    corrupt, try re-installing it using RLinkResourcesInstall with an option
    Update->True 

Out[4]= $Failed

Answer (score 4):

This will be fixed in a matter of a few weeks, we do have more recent versions of R (3.6.x) in the works, to be bundled for RLink for Mac and Windows (the support for bundled R will be dropped for Linux). In the mean time, in addition to the link provided in comments, have a look also at [this Q/A on Wolfram Community](https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/1807709), where the procedure to use external R distribution has been described in detail.